# Replace/decorate `translation.reader`

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I filled a bug but it seams I'm off :p

I just want to replace the service `Symfony\Component\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader` (`translation.reader`) with my own class. In fact I want to know how to replace any service of SF4 if I want

`translation.reader::addLoader()` is normally called by the framework but if I decorate with my own class `addLoader` is not called.

Can you tell me how I can just drop replace my own service ?

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28843

**Symfony version(s) affected**: 4.1.6

**Description**
Cannot decorate **translation.reader** (I want to change the default i18n file loading process)

**How to reproduce**

copy/adapt `Symfony\Component\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader` to `App\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader`

Follow https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Modify `services.yaml`

```
Symfony\Component\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader: ~

App\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader:
    decorates: Symfony\Component\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader

#translation.reader: '@App\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader'
```

Without the alias : the new service is ignored
With the alias : `read()` is trigger but not `addLoader()`

Here are the generated injection file `getTranslationReaderService.php` :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException;

// This file has been auto-generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component for internal use.
// Returns the private 'App\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader' shared autowired service.

include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Reader/TranslationReaderInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/src/Translation/Reader/TranslationReader.php';

return $this->privates['App\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader'] = new \App\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader();
```

By default it looks like :

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException;

// This file has been auto-generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component for internal use.
// Returns the private 'translation.reader' shared service.

include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Reader/TranslationReaderInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Reader/TranslationReader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/LoaderInterface.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/ArrayLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/FileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/PhpFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/XliffFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/PoFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/MoFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/QtFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/CsvFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/IcuResFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/IcuDatFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/IniFileLoader.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/JsonFileLoader.php';

$this->privates['translation.reader'] = $instance = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader();

$a = ($this->privates['translation.loader.yml'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.yml'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader());
$b = ($this->privates['translation.loader.xliff'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.xliff'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader());

$instance->addLoader('php', ($this->privates['translation.loader.php'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.php'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\PhpFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('yaml', $a);
$instance->addLoader('yml', $a);
$instance->addLoader('xlf', $b);
$instance->addLoader('xliff', $b);
$instance->addLoader('po', ($this->privates['translation.loader.po'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.po'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\PoFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('mo', ($this->privates['translation.loader.mo'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.mo'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\MoFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('ts', ($this->privates['translation.loader.qt'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.qt'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\QtFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('csv', ($this->privates['translation.loader.csv'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.csv'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\CsvFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('res', ($this->privates['translation.loader.res'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.res'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\IcuResFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('dat', ($this->privates['translation.loader.dat'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.dat'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\IcuDatFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('ini', ($this->privates['translation.loader.ini'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.ini'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\IniFileLoader()));
$instance->addLoader('json', ($this->privates['translation.loader.json'] ?? $this->privates['translation.loader.json'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\JsonFileLoader()));

return $instance;
```

You can see that loaders are not injected when I do the decorating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work... but please feel free to comment

I had to create a `TranslatorPass` to add loaders to the decorating service injection file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Translation\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use App\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader;

class TranslatorPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    private $readerServiceId;
    private $loaderTag;

    public function __construct(string $readerServiceId = TranslationReader::class, string $loaderTag = 'translation.loader')
    {
        $this->readerServiceId = $readerServiceId;
        $this->loaderTag = $loaderTag;
    }

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loaders = array();
        $loaderRefs = array();
        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds($this->loaderTag, true) as $id => $attributes) {
            $loaderRefs[$id] = new Reference($id);
            $loaders[$id][] = $attributes[0]['alias'];
            if (isset($attributes[0]['legacy-alias'])) {
                $loaders[$id][] = $attributes[0]['legacy-alias'];
            }
        }

        if ($container->hasDefinition($this->readerServiceId)) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($this->readerServiceId);
            foreach ($loaders as $id => $formats) {
                foreach ($formats as $format) {
                    $definition->addMethodCall('addLoader', array($format, $loaderRefs[$id]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've put it in the `Kernel.php`

```
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);
    $container->addCompilerPass(new TranslatorPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, 1000);
}
```

then

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

et voilà !

Comment: I had toyed with Silex many years and I'm not used to 'structured' injection... I'm not sure I like the sophistication of SF :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly if this is the root of your problem, but here are some remarks. Hopefully this will help you find a solution, even though I'm not actually given a full answer to your question.

1) Some translation services in Symfony are called *only* during the cache warmup phase. Whenever you change your config, or do a `bin/console cache:clear`, you'll see these classes are run, and they generate translations in your `var/cache/<env>/translations/` folder.

2) You can try to make sure that in your cache, the classe loaded by `var/cache/<env>/Container<...>/getTranslation_ReaderService.php` is yours and not the default one like this:

```
$this->privates['translation.reader'] = 
    new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader();
```

3) I also encountered a similar issue in the `dev` environment, where I was trying to replace `Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator` with my own service, and didn't manage to get my methods to be called at first. Part of the explanation was that when the Symfony Profiler is enabled, Symfony does something like this (in `src<env>DebugProjectContainer.php>`):

```
$this->services['translator'] = new \Symfony\Component\Translation\DataCollectorTranslator(
    ($this->privates['translator.default'] ?? $this->getTranslator_DefaultService())
);
```

and the `DataCollectorTranslator` itself is a wrapper for whichever translator it gets as its constructor argument.

I know this is not a perfect answer but hopefully this will help you find your way to a solution.

Comment: it's a good pointer now I can "see" the generated injection files but it's not (yet) working